# Button Bug (CodeIgniter & Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

Coding Follow/Unfollow system in CodeIgniter(PHP) & Twitter-Bootstrap. Am also having routes active for the URLS. Follow Button code in VIEW.

```
 <!-- Follow Button Start -->
<?php $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'); ?>
<?php if(!(empty($is_logged_in)) && $sID != $vID && !in_array($sID, $following)): ?>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" onClick="location.href='<?php echo site_url("follow/$vUsername"); ?>'">Follow <?php echo $vUsername; ?> </button>
<?php elseif (in_array($sID, $following)):?>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" onClick="location.href='<?php echo site_url("unfollow/$vUsername"); ?>'">UnFollow <?php echo $vUsername; ?> </button>
<?php else: ?>
    <button class="btn disabled" type="submit">Follow <?php echo $vUsername; ?> </button>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- Follow Button End -->
```

Even If the User is not Following than too the Button shows `UnFollow $vUsername`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't fully test it here, but this would make more sense to me:

```
<?php if((!empty($is_logged_in)) && ($sID != $vID) && (!in_array($sID, $following))): ?>
```

*Edit:*

Well, in that case, only simple step-by-step debugging will save you:

```
<?php 
$is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'); 

if(!empty($is_logged_in))
{
    echo '$is_logged_in is not empty';
}

echo '$sID is: '.$sID.' and it should not be equal to $vID'. $vID;

if($sID != $vID){
    echo 'and indeed it is not';
}
else
{
    echo 'but it is. Here is the problem';
}

echo 'This is the $following array:';
print_r($following);

if(!in_array($sID, $following))
{
    echo '$sID is not in the $following array';
}
else
{
    echo '$sID IS in the $following array';
}   

?>
```

Comment: Tested that, Still no luck!
**$sID = $this->session->userdata('id');
$vID = $this->m_user->fetch_id($data['vUsername']); //fetches User ID
$following is the array of followers as obtained from DB.**

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, your initial code is hard to read already

Comment: Missed a ";". That's really something that you should be able to solve yourself instead of just posting the error here.... I edited my code... you're welcome